# Disable validation of identifiers in Byte Buddy

Tags: java, jvm, byte-buddy

I am working on a JVM-based programming language and I use Byte Buddy for the code generator. The language is somewhat similar to Java but typically uses annotations where Java would use keywords. Some example annotations are `public`, `private`, `extends`, `override`, `singleton` or `inject`.

Unlike the Java *Language* Specification, the Java *Virtual Machine* Specification imposes very few restrictions on class names, and names like `extends` or `public` are perfectly valid from JVM-perspective.
However, when I try to generate annotation classes with a name that happens to be a Java keyword I get an `IllegalStateException` "`Illegal type name`" from Byte Buddy's `InstrumentedType` class.

How can I circumvent the validation that is specific to the Java language and use more lenient validation rules that follow the Java Virtual Machine Specification instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply disable validation:

```
new ByteBuddy().with(TypeValidation.DISABLED);
```

Comment: Haha, thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize that type validation also included the name checking for reserved keywords.

Answer (score 0):

After studying the Byte Buddy sources for a bit, I might have found a solution, but it's extremely hacky and hopefully someone knows a better way...

Luckily for me, the `KEYWORDS` field in `net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.InstrumentedType.Default` uses just a plain mutable `HashSet` instead of a `Collections.unmodifiableSet`, so with the following hack I was able to remove the validation of Java keywords:

```
val Field KEYWORDS = Default.getDeclaredField("KEYWORDS")
KEYWORDS.setAccessible(true)
val Set<String> keywords = KEYWORDS.get(null) as Set<String>
keywords.clear
```

(the code is written in [Xtend](https://www.eclipse.org/xtend/) syntax, but you get the idea)

That being said, I'm the first one to admit that using Java Reflection to poke around in `final` `static` fields of other libraries isn't exactly best practice. So, whereas my immediate blocker is removed I'm hoping that there is a more orthodox solution to this problem...

Comment: Yes, please don't do that, you might just break with a future version and will not work when using Byte Buddy as a module. You can disable validation, simple as that.